# sklearn knn prediction error: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, knn

I'm trying to feed a record to knn.predict() to make a prediction by using the following code:

```
person_features = {
 'cma': 462, # Metropolitan area
 'agegrp': 9, # Age Group
 'sex': 1, 
 'ageimm': 6, # Age group at immigration
 'immstat': 1, # Immigrant status
 'pob': 21, # Other Eastern Asia
 'nol': 4, # First languages
 'cip2011': 7, # Major field of study: Mathematics, computer and information     sciences
 'hdgree': 12, # Hightest Education
}

prediction = knn.predict(person_features)
labels={True: '>50K', False: '<=50K'}
print(labels[prediction])
```

But it showed

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'

I tried making it into list of tuples like:

```
person_features= [('cma',462), ('agegrp',9), ('sex',1), ('ageimm',6), ('immstat',1), ('pob',21), ('nol',4), ('cip2011',7), ('hdgree',12)])
```

But didnt work either.

What should I do to solve this type error? I feel like the solution is easy, but somehow I just could wrap my head around it.

Comment: It's expecting a numpy array of floats, you're passing a dict, you need to convert your input data to a numpy array containing just the values see the example here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html#k-nearest-neighbors-classifier

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I then tried 
inputData = np.ndarray(shape=(1,10))
inputData=[462,12,1,6,1,21,4,7,12,1]
And it worked :) Though I'm not happy with the prediction cause it's saying I'm going to make less than <50K lol

Answer (score 3):

New to programming and just started to learn Python less than three month. So bear with me for my amateur questions and answer!

```
# I looked up the numbers from the coding book
cma = 462
agegrp = 9
sex = 1
ageimm = 6 
immstat = 1 
pob = 21
nol = 4
cip2011 =7  
hdgree = 12
MoreThan50K = 1 # what I am going to predict, 1 for >50K, 0 for <50K 

person_features = [cma, agegrp, sex, ageimm, immstat, pob, nol, cip2011, hdgree, MoreThan50K]
prediction = knn.predict(person_features)
```

So it was pretty straightforward afterall.